# How to compute location of my mouse pointer on some 3D object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, mouse, coordinate-transformation

Are there any built-in means to compute an intersection, corresponding to a ray, representing mouse pointer (or touching finger) with some object in the scene?

For example, if I have a sphere, can I compute UV coordinates on it (without writing math myself)?

Comment: `ScreenPointToRay`, then `RayCast`?  Pretty sure `RayCastHitInfo` gives all that sort of data back.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mesh than there is a [UV property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-uv.html) on it already. As far as sending a raycast out from where the user clicks / touches, you will need to do a little bit of work yourself.

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
        Transform objectHit = hit.transform;

        // Do something with the object that was hit by the raycast.
    }
```

I pulled that chunk of code from the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CameraRays.html).

If you need the exact location of the ray hit on the object, than you can use `hit.point` ([docs for hit.point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html))

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html